# “fse.node” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. While doing npm run dev or watch

Tags: macos, catalina, permission, gatekeeper

On macOS Catalina 10.15.3, I am getting the below error message while running `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`. It seems like something to do with `nodejs` but no idea know how to resolve it.

> “fse.node” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
>   macOS cannot verify that this app is free from malware.

[image]